# Create Google chrome Extension with Kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-js

I have a situation where I am trying to create a google chrome extension using KotlinJs and I was following the Rivas Diaz (https://github.com/rivasdiaz/helloworld-chrome-extension-kotlin).
With this, I tried building the demo but there are some issues in the building extension and it stuck at 60% of the progress every time, I am sharing the screenshot as well so if anyone has any idea can help me with the same.
I am sharing the screenshot link here

[image]